# add conditional row between two tables to query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
TABLE items (id, title, price)
TABLE purchases (id, item_id, user_id)
```

I need to select all items for a specific user (given `user_id`), and add a 4th column to `items` table as a flag to know if a user purchased the item previously but don't know how to achieve this in mysql.

```
SELECT items.id, items.title, items.price, purchased FROM items, purchases...
```

Comment: What happens if a user only has 2 items (i.e. there is no sequential fourth row)?

Comment: items are like purchasable goods, not owned by users, purchases do belong to specific users. I want to get a list of all available products (ready to use, ready to purchase) will be the flag that I am asking for.

Comment: Wait...do you mean add a fourth column instead of row?

Comment: been working for too long, yes I do. Edited the question.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, because an `INNER JOIN` will automatically remove all items which were not purchased.  Do you want to show all items for all users?

Comment: single query to list all avaiable products for a single user, and also identify the owned ones by him/her. E.g. Here is a list of all items, and there is 40 items, these 10, are the ones you own.

Comment: Actually, I think we may need your user table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.price,
    CASE WHEN p.user_id = 'users_id' THEN 'purchased' ELSE 'not purchased' END AS flag
FROM items i LEFT JOIN purchases p ON i.id = p.item_id
```

Comment: For future reference, if you post sample input as well as your expected output, you will get an answer much faster.  A picture is worth a thousand words on Stack Overflow.